# Stored procedure with Hibernate fails in embedded h2 database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, h2

Im saving data to myRepository1 and to be able to see the savings via the materialized view, i need to refresh it.

```
      myRepository1.save(myObject);
      myRepository2.refreshView();
```

myRepository2 has:

```
        @Modifying
        @Query(value = "BEGIN my_refresh_view(); END;", nativeQuery = true)
        void refreshView();
```

Where my_refresh_view is a simple stored procedure.
This works fine in the real world (Oracle DB) - however, when i run my integration tests for the code above using an embedded h2 database, i get:

```
BEGIN my_refresh_view(); END; [42000-200]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException could not prepare statement;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
```

Looks like the stored procedure and h2 dont match well together.

Any ideas how to make it work, or maybe there are workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate JPA (at least 5.0.0 and below) does not support stored procedures for H2Dialect.H2Dialect inherits Dialect.getCallableStatementSupport() which returns StandardCallableStatementSupport.NO_REF_CURSOR_INSTANCE. The standard callable statement support does not properly handle the H2 "out" parameter which is a Java return value and not a statement parameter
[check details here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10075?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)